# Getting a "no printer attached" error after hotend swap out

Tags: troubleshooting, artillery-sidewinder-x1

I have an Artillery Sidewinder X1 that had a stripped-out screw. I couldn't find a single screw anywhere and opted to replace the entire hot end, screws, fans, and everything. Should have been pretty easy, and was - 3 screws and a ribbon cable. Now when I turn on the printer I get the "no printer attached error" on the TFT display.

I've searched Google and can find no help there.
Any ideas would be gratefully accepted!

Firmware: RAWR 28.x
Board: TFT version Artillery (stock)

Comment: Hi welcome to 3DPrinting.SE! Please describe which application throws the `no printer attached` message, or is this the printer display? Long shot, but are you sure the flat cable is connected and properly inserted?

Comment: Sorry if I'm not very clear, but of course I'm new here.  This is a stock 18 month old Artillery Sidewinder X1, with the exception of the RAWR firmware which has been working perfectly.  I had problems with the hotend hardware and just replaced the whole thing.  As I mentioned above, it was just 3 screws and the ribbon cable.  Should have been easy.  Now when I turn on the printer I get the "no printer attached error" on the TFT display.  I appreciate your comment and it has me wondering if there is a problem with the ribbon cable.  Shouldn't be but I'll check.  I open to any ideas you have!

Comment: Just to eliminate errors, maybe you could use the ribbon cable from the old hotend to check. Also, and this would be a right pain admittedly, as a sanity check maybe just temporarily wire back in the old hotend to see if the old hotend assembly (now) gives the same error (as previously it presumably didn't). After that, it could be a process of elimination, swapping each part in turn, checking to see which new part is causing the issue. Also, possible disassembly and reassembly might magically fix any dodgy connection or wiring that occurred during the initial swap out. Just some thoughts...